# how to make a HTTP request in Swift

Tags: swift

**Code**

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error ) in
    if error == nil {                
            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)            
            println(urlContent)
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.stackoverflow.com")!
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if let data = data {
            if let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                println(urlContent)
            }
        } else if let error = error {
            println(error.description)
        }
    }
    //
}

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Apple docs for `dataTaskWithURL(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:).

> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its resume method.